# Testing repository class which uses service as dependencies which is exported from another module

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

I am currently facing a problem while testing my ControllerV1 class which is using another module ServiceA class as a dependency.

ServiceA ---> RepositoryA & RepositoryB as dependency.
RepositoryB ---> Uses ServiceD from AnotherModule which is exported.

So currently I have imported that module into my Testing module which is not a good approach. Otherwise I am getting dependency errors.

e.g

```
const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
  imports: [AnotherModule],
  providers: [
    Service,
    RepositoryA,
    RepositoryB, // It uses Service from AnotherModule as dependency
    {
      provide: 'MockRepository',
      useValue: {},
    },
    {
      provide: 'MockModel',
      useValue: {},
    },
  ],
  controllers: [ControllerV1],
}).compile();
```

Comment: add `{ provide: ServiceD, useValue: {},}`

Comment: I did but it requires dependencies. That is why I am confuse how to handle that scenario